# Why changing character into date format gives me NA values?

Tags: r, time-series, as.date

I have a timeseries dataset in R with a monthly temporal resolution. But in the data frame there is day/month/year included which does not make any sense, I mean the (day). So firstly I have converted the date into the as.Date format by using this code.

```
Data$Month <- as.Date(Data$Month, format = '%m/%d/%Y')

Result: > `head(Data$Month)`
[1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01"
[6] "2016-01-01"
```

Which works perfectly. Now I have created another column by using this code from the previous Month column which include only Month_Yr.

```
Data$Month_Yr <- format(as.Date(Data$Month), "%m/%Y")

Result: > head(Data$Month_Yr)
[1] "01/2016" "01/2016" "01/2016" "01/2016" "01/2016" "01/2016"
```

This newly column (Month_Yr) class in Character. Now I want to change this newly created column into as.Date format by using this code.

```
Data$Month_Yr <- as.Date(Data$Month_Yr, format = "%m/%Y")
```

But when I did this column is converted into NA values.

```
Result: > head(Data$Month_Yr)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: The Date type can't handle month/year values. It needs a proper date (it needs to know what day of the month it is.) See duplicate for options (like hard coding the first day of the month) or using a different type.

Comment: When you put a character result back into a dataframe column, it becomes a `factor`-class. There is a yearmon class defined in the zoo package.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the correction. I've had so much trouble over the years with factors that I immediately assume that is the root of any question.